# Can't access Nexus proxy repository data

Tags: repository, nexus

Got Nexus Repository Manager OSS, where I set up a proxy repository to another Nexus (Professional edition). Routing information is Ok, appears as published and Discovery is successfull. I can browser remote repository, but nothing appears under Browser Index tab.

When I try accessing the repository via http (e.g. http://myserver.net/nexus/content/repositories/MyRepository/org/) - I receive this error:
404 - Request is marked as local-only, remote access not allowed from M2Repository

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't retrieve a directory through a proxy repository, you need to send a request for an actual artifact file that exists on the remote, e.g. "http://myserver.net/nexus/content/repositories/MyRepository/org/foo/someproject/1.0/someproject-1.0.jar".

Comment: I get same error when requesting actual artifact: 404 - Path /org/foo/someproject/maven-metadata.xml4 not found in local nor in remote storage of M2Repository

Answer (score 0):

After researching a while, found that artifacts are indexed only after downloading them via Nexus server found in the middle, between me and remote Nexus.

As of error, causing it was a bad URL, unfortunately I miss-typed an artifact name in the URL address.